# Using document.querySelectorAll to find a specific node based on its class and inner text

Tags: javascript

The html looks something like the following:

```
<div>
    <div class='some-class'>
    some text
    </div>
    <div class='some-class'>
    some other text
    </div>
...
</div>
```

I'm trying to use something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[class*=some-class]')
```

But I don't know how to filter by the node's text I thought I could use foreach and find or contains like the following but that didn't work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[style*=some-class ]').filter('some text')
```

How can I achieve this with a one liner?

Comment: well you said you want to use filter, but you are not using `filter()`

Comment: I've tried with filter it didn't work. See my update. Can you suggest an answer using filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the elements, convert it to an array, and use find

```js
const elem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.some-class'))
               .find(x => x.textContent.trim() === 'some text')
console.log(elem)
```

```html
<div class='some-class'>
  some text
</div>
<div class='some-class'> some other text
</div>
```

If there can be more than one match, you need to use filter

```js
const elem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.some-class'))
               .filter(x => x.textContent.trim() === 'some text')
console.log(elem)
```

```html
<div class='some-class'>
  some text
</div>
<div class='some-class'> some other text
</div>
<div class='some-class'>
  some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `filter` and then match the `innerText`.

You need to use `Array.from()` because `NodeList` doesn't have its own `.filter()` method.

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class*=some-class]')).filter(e => e.innerText.trim() == "some text"))
```

```html
<div class='some-class'>
  some text
</div>
<div class='some-class'>
  some other text
</div>
```

Use `.trim()` to remove the newlines around the text.

The filtering function can use any string operations you want, such as `.includes()` to look for a substring, or regular expression matching.

Comment: Can I use wildcards or something similar to contains() and if yes how?

Comment: You can use the `.includes()` method.

Comment: `innerText` is just a string, you can use anything that works with strings, including regular expressions.